# Solution of Set of Differential Equations $x' = y$ and $y' = {2\over t^2}x - {2\over t}y $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There exists a set of differential equations, $x' = y$ and $y' = {2\over t^2}x - {2\over t}y $

Now, willing to find the solution, which is y(t).

First, I had tried to differentiate both sides of the second equation to use the first equation which contains first derivative of $x'$, however, when I differentiate the second equations with respect to $t$, there still exists $x$.

Any hints to proceed?

Comment: $x'$ is $\frac{dx}{dt}$ or $\frac{dx}{dy}$?

Comment: the first one, derivation wrt t

Answer (score 1):

with $$x'=y$$ we get $$x''=y'$$ and our equation will be
$$x''=\frac{2}{t^2}x-\frac{2}{t}x'$$

Comment: One could mention that the resulting ODE is of Euler type with basis solutions $t$ and $t^{-2}$.

Comment: thank you for the hint on the morning!